# Query returning a zero when dividing in the select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i try to divide the first nested select statement by the count of a column, the query returns a zero. When I replace the "/" with a ",", I receive two different numbers so the return value shouldn't be a zero. Could this have something to do with there being zeros in the data set? Any help would be appreciated

```
declare @hospitalfk int;
set @hospitalfk='1335'

declare @startdate date;
set @startdate='03/01/2014'

declare @enddate date;
set @enddate='02/28/2015'

declare @reportname varchar(50);
set @reportname='%Medicaid Billable Report%'

declare @metasectionname varchar(100);
set @metasectionname='Medicaid Primary'

select 
(
select count(iscoded)
from ope.ope.vwerali 
    where iscoded=1 
        and hospitalfk=@hospitalfk
        and reportdate between @startdate and @enddate
        and reportname like @reportname
        and metasectionname like @metasectionname
)
/count(iscoded)
from ope.ope.vwerali
    where hospitalfk=@hospitalfk
        and reportdate between @startdate and @enddate
        and reportname like @reportname
        and metasectionname like @metasectionname
```

Comment: "I receive two different numbers".. what numbers do you receive? Counts return integers. Without casting to another datatype, and you have a denominator > your numerator, you'll get 0 as a result. Example: `select 1/2`

Comment: Like Dan said, but to be a little more specific...  Wrap your denominator in a CAST(nullif(count(iscoded),0) as float).  SQL Server handles integer division differently than regular math.  The Nullif will prevent divide by zero errors

Comment: The nested select statement returns 2484 and the count(iscoded) returns 3569. I've tried converting the columns to int, but the query still returns a zero.

Comment: Kevin, I'll try cast instead of convert. thanks.

Comment: CONVERT will work just as well as CAST, but it needs to be converted to float or numeric, not int.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I've got it returning the expected value. I've updated my answer with your suggestion below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for two selects, simply use a Case statement for count.

Also I think you are trying to avoid a Zero `0` in divisor.

Also for date parameters pass date values as ANSI Date i.e `YYYYMMDD`

```
select count(CASE WHEN iscoded=1  THEN iscoded END) * 1.00
      / NULLIF(count(iscoded), 0) 
from ope.ope.vwerali 
    where  hospitalfk=@hospitalfk
        and reportdate between @startdate and @enddate
        and reportname like @reportname
        and metasectionname like @metasectionname
```

Comment: unfortunately, this still returns a zero.

Comment: @WSL346 Try now first it was casting it as int now it should return decimals

Comment: I solved my problem using another method, but this answer works as well and is a lot more compact. Thanks @M.Ali

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @hospitalfk int;
set @hospitalfk='1335'

declare @startdate date;
set @startdate='03/01/2014'

declare @enddate date;
set @enddate='02/28/2015'

declare @reportname varchar(50);
set @reportname='%Medicaid Billable Report%'

declare @metasectionname varchar(100);
set @metasectionname='Medicaid Primary'

select 
(
    select CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),count(iscoded))
    from ope.ope.vwerali 
    where iscoded=1 
        and hospitalfk=@hospitalfk
        and reportdate between @startdate and @enddate
        and reportname like @reportname
        and metasectionname like @metasectionname
)
/CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),count(iscoded))
from ope.ope.vwerali
    where hospitalfk=@hospitalfk
        and reportdate between @startdate and @enddate
        and reportname like @reportname
        and metasectionname like @metasectionname
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it returning the expected value I was looking for. Credit goes to Kevin Suchlicki. All I needed to do was change:

```
count(iscoded)
```

to

```
convert(float,nullif(count(iscoded),0))
```

Updated query

```
declare @hospitalfk int;
set @hospitalfk='1335'

declare @startdate date;
set @startdate='03/01/2014'

declare @enddate date;
set @enddate='02/28/2015'

declare @reportname varchar(50);
set @reportname='%Medicaid Billable Report%'

declare @metasectionname varchar(100);
set @metasectionname='Medicaid Primary'

select 
(
select convert(float,nullif(count(iscoded),0))
from ope.ope.vwerali 
    where iscoded=1 and hospitalfk=@hospitalfk
        and reportdate between @startdate and @enddate
        and reportname like @reportname
        and metasectionname like @metasectionname
)
/convert(float,nullif(count(iscoded),0))
from ope.ope.vwerali
    where hospitalfk=@hospitalfk
        and reportdate between @startdate and @enddate
        and reportname like @reportname
        and metasectionname like @metasectionname
```